# stackexchange.com/sites still uses the old [B] icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, stack-exchange, favicon

[image]

Comment: +1 freehand drop shadow

Comment: +2 for freehand drop shadow

Comment: Gafcwaprma... stackexchange.com is going to be my new "Periodic Table of Naming".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are coming from the API, which was out of sync for a couple of days.

Now that the API has caught up, StackExchange should likewise catch up soon.

---

StackExchange.com has now caught up.